# displaying one too many items rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a simple app and in many views I am displaying all of the objects associated with a certain model (many-to-one relationship).  For example, I have a house model and an Item model where House has many Items.  On the Show view for house I have the following code:

```
<% @house.items.each do |item| %>
    <% if item.needed == true%>
        <p>
        <%= item.description %>
        </p>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and this displays all the items along with one blank item.  If I delete all the items, leaving an empty array there is still one empty item remaining.  I can hack this using the code:

```
<% @house.items[0..-2].each do |item| %>
    <% if item.needed == true%>
        <p>
        <%= item.description %>
        </p>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This is probably a really simple question, but I would like to avoid using the latter code, and would like to understand why this is happening.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have blank items in the DB? and is needed a boolean field, you should be able to say `if item.needed?`

Comment: try `if item and item.needed` the first check is for *truthiness*

Comment: i have needed as a boolean attribute (this may not be the best way to accomplish what I want... I am pretty sure I dont have blank items in the DB, I have called `delete_all` on items in the db and this still happens

Comment: Also this happens if I take the boolean query out

Comment: You're probably doing something like `@item = @house.items.build` in your controller to set up a new item (your `show` page might also have a form on it somewhere?) Because of this, `@items` is including that empty new object...

Comment: Why is it being included if the item built in the `show` action isnt saved to the db?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are seeing is data related. This is to say, you need to figure out what is being returned by @house.items. Perhaps you have an item that has needed == true and a blank description? To trouble shoot this verify what is being returned by the house object in question by opening up the rails console, loading the house object in question and checking what is returned by house.items.

Comment: I have looked at this, and run house.items.delete_all, so that house.items returns an empty array and this still happens.  In the show action of my House controller I do run `@item = @house.item.new`, but this is not being saved, it is just called to pass the item off in the params hash, how would this be saved in the db?

Comment: Try removing the @house.item.new call and see if it changes your output :-)

Answer (score 0):

When using `@house.items.new` to set up a new `Item` object, it will alter the `@house.items` array, even though the new item is not yet persisted to the database. Example:

```
items = @house.items
items.length
# => 3
item = @house.items.new
items.length
# => 4
```

You could either add a check inside your loop for something like `if item.persisted?` or `unless item.new_record?`. Or, you could build the new item this way instead, which won't include it in `@house.items` until it's actually saved to the database:

```
item = Item.new(house_id: @house.id, needed: true)
```